# to change login mode of centos 6.5

Tags: login, gui, virtual-consoles

I have been using CentOS 6.5 with the command line for 6 month. (It has database.) When I tried a graphical login, I got ... *Open this file: vi `/etc/inittab` using a text editor and change the following line: `id:3:initdefault:` To: `id:5:initdefault`* but when I restart my pc, I don't see anything and I can't access anything from my pc.

When I open my pc process to open when finished the monitor sleeped. How can I change it to text mode without formating and losing data? Please help me.

Comment: install xorg and a wm

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you changed the runlevel of your machine from 3 to 5 and now you get blank screen after booting up?

If yes, then change it back :)

If it is just display settings you could try loggin there via ssh from different machine.

You can boot from some cd or usb stick, mount your root partition, edit the file, umount and reboot.

You can boot in single user level from legacy grub:

1. While in grub choose (with arrows) boot entry you want to edit
2. Press e to edit entry
3. Find line beggining with **linux** and add **init=/bin/bash** there
4. Boot system with those settings (**b** key, if I remember correctly)
5. Most probably you will have to remount your root filesystem

   mount -o remount,rw /
6. Edit file and reboot

When you will get your box back it is easier to check X configuration from console by simply issuing **startx** command (of course after some configuration and not from root user). You can also switch to other runlevel manually: **init 5**. If something goes wrong you just reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch to a different virtual console press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd> etc.

If the current runlevel doesn't provide a virtual console, then the boot menu (e.g. grub) could be an option top boot into a different run level (e.g. single user mode, which is for recovery).

If there is no boot menu provided, then you have to boot from a rescue system or from the installation media, which provide terminals and other features to repair the damage.